# URL changes when using ErrorDocument 403 in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, web, http-status-code-403

I have written a .htaccess file to make sure that visitors are always redirected to https and to www. In addition to that I have also added a custom html page for 404 errors.

When visitors try to access a forbidden file I want them to see my custom 404 message, as to not reveal that the path contains a forbidden file.

Here is the problem. When writing for example "example-domain.com/.htaccess" (no www or https) in the browser, the URL in the address field in the browser changes to "https://www.example-domain.com/missing.html". But I want it to say "https://www.example-domain.com/.htaccess" while displaying my 404 page.

It works for 404 errors. But when typing in a path in the address field which both triggers the 403 error and fulfill at least one of the rewrite conditions in my .htaccess file (missing https and/or www) I experience the above described problem.

Here is the code in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

ErrorDocument 403 /missing.html
ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
```

Best regards

Comment: What you describe shouldn't happen with the directives posted on Apache (or LiteSpeed). What webserver are you on / version? How is `.htaccess` being blocked? Can you confirm the HTTP redirects (and status codes) you are seeing in the browser. Do you have any other directives in the `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files? Server config?